# How to delete object and all references?

Tags: javascript

We use the `delete` when we need to delete the object reference. But is there any way in JS to delete the entire object and all references?

**Example:**

```
let obj = {
    a: 3
}
let arr = [obj];
let brr = [obj];
```

If I'd change the `obj` items in the arrays would be changed too.
Also, I can use `delete arr[0]` to delete the reference.
But I want to delete the `obj` and I want the items in the arrays to be deleted too.

**Something like:**

```
// Before: 
let obj = {
   a: 3
}
let arr = [obj];
let brr = [obj];
arr.length==1 // true
brr.length==1 // true
// Deleting:
delete(obj)
// After:
arr.length==0 // true
brr.length==0 // true
```

Comment: afaik there is no mecanism allowing this in javascript

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - What is the actual problem you try to solve with this?

Comment: Thank you, @Andreas, I've done the edit

Comment: I recommend you to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: The only way to do this if you use some sort of data management library such as React, or RxJS. Then, when an object is removed, the arrays are regenerated and will become empty.

Comment: Probably you want [javascript - Removing all properties from a object - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316857/removing-all-properties-from-a-object) instead. Not exactly what you want but we don't understand what you reallyi want at all.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the closest thing I can do is delete the properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The only way to delete an object in JavaScript is to locate and delete each reference to it.

There's no generic mechanism to start with an object and automatically delete all references to it.